# Create a new table based on existing other table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have tables like this:

Table_0

| CustomerID | Trans_date |
| --- | --- |
| C001 | 01-sep-22 |
| C001 | 04-sep-22 |
| C001 | 14-sep-22 |
| C002 | 03-sep-22 |
| C002 | 01-sep-22 |

Table_1

| CustomerID | Trans_date |
| --- | --- |
| C002 | 18-sep-22 |
| C002 | 20-sep-22 |
| C003 | 02-sep-22 |
| C003 | 28-sep-22 |

Table_2

| CustomerID | Trans_date |
| --- | --- |
| C004 | 08-sep-22 |
| C004 | 18-sep-22 |
| C004 | 20-sep-22 |
| C005 | 18-sep-22 |

How to create a new table where the new table consists of table_0, table_1 and table_2 in postgresql? thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table, like for exemple 'new_table', then do this command for each of your table: `INSERT INTO new_tale SELECT * FROM table_0`

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
select a.CustomerID ac customer_id,
a.Trans_date as Trans_date1,
b.Trans_date as Trans_date2, 
c.Trans_date as Trans_date3
where a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
and b.CustomerID=c.CustomerID;
```

Comment: @cillawclarss create a table with this select!!

Answer (score 0):

union example: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-union/
create table as: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-create-table-as/

follow the example would be:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        Trans_date
    FROM
        Table_0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        Trans_date
    FROM
        Table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        Trans_date
    FROM
        Table_2)
```